# Is there a way to save all Greenshot Captures in a folder but not temporary folder?

Tags: windows-10, greenshot

When capturing with greenshot the capture is saved in %TEMP% where it eventually gets deleted.

Is there a way to save all the captures automatically to a specific greenshot folder so they do not get deleted after some time?

Comment: In output settings > screenshot destination you should be able to define a different folder.